# заменить 0 на unknown

Tags: java

Есть перезагруженный метод toString() и он выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но нужно при выводе заменить 0.0 на unknown (пример ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    
    return "AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt="+body_wt+", brainWt="+brain_wt+", nonDreaming=" + non_dreaming+
            ", dreaming="+ dreaming+ ", totalSleep="+total_sleep+", lifeSpan="+life_span+", gestation="+
            gestation+", predation="+predation+", exposure="+exposure+", danger="+danger+"}";
}
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте метод

```
private String getValue(double value){
  return value == 0? "unknown": value;
}
```

И замените. Выражение типа

```
AnimalCharacteristics{bodyWt="+getValue (body_wt)+"....
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пользуйтесь на здоровье